# Minimizer of $\int\mu({\rm d}x)\int\kappa(x,{\rm d}y)|g(x)-g(y)|^2$ for a jump kernel $\kappa$ of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm

Tags: optimization, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, measure-theory, optimal-scaling

Let $\kappa$ be a sub-Markov kernel on a measurable space $(E,\mathcal E)$ and $\mu$ be a probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ reversible with respect to $\kappa$. Assume $\kappa$ and $\mu$ admit a density $k:E^2\to[0,\infty)$ and $p:E\to[0,\infty)$ with respect to a common reference measure $\lambda$ on $(E,\mathcal E)$. Feel free to assume that $\kappa$ is the jump kernel of a Metropolis-Hastings kernel.

I'm interested in the quantity $$\inf_{\substack{g\in L^2(\mu)\\g\ge0\\g\text{ is bounded}\\\mu g=0\\\mu|g|^2=1}}\int\mu({\rm d}x)\int\kappa(x,{\rm d}y)|g(x)-g(y)|^2=\inf_{\substack{g\in L^2(\mu)\\g\ge0\\g\text{ is bounded}\\\mu g=0\\\mu|g|^2=1}}\left\|\psi g\right\|_{L^2(\mu\otimes\kappa)}^2\tag1,$$ where $$\psi g:=\left(E^2\ni(x,y)\mapsto g(x)-g(y)\right)\;\;\;\text{for }g:E\to\mathbb R.$$

> Is there any way to obtain the minimizer of $(1)$?

*Remark*: Please take note of my related question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/347894/91890.

Comment: You are (essentially) asking to compute the spectral gap of the Markov chain with transition kernel $\kappa$; this is very difficult and can typically only be carried out in very basic cases  (finite state spaces, or $\mu, \kappa$ both Gaussian). To even establish bounds on the spectral gap typically requires a lot of specific information about both $\mu$ and $\kappa$.

Comment: @πr8 Yes, maximizing the spectral gap is precisely what I want to do. In my particular scenario, it's sufficient to maximize $(1)$. The precise form of the $\kappa$ I'm interested in is given in the mathoverflow question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/347894/91890.

Comment: What you are asking is still _far_ too general. I would emphasise that even for a specific $\mu$, and a specific $\kappa$, it is very hard to calculate a spectral gap, let alone maximise it. If you can write down an explicit $\mu$ and $\kappa$, there may be some hope, but it will of course depend on the specifics.

Comment: @πr8 Okay, thanks for noting that. See, my actual goal is to minimize the asymptotic variance of the Metropolis-Hastings estimators corresponding to the $\kappa_w$ (in the MO question). One way is maximizing the spectral gap. But if this is too hard: I don't necessarily need to actually *minimize* the asymptotic variance, but choose $(w_i)_{i\in I}$ such they significantly reduce the asymptotic variance. Do you see any chance to do that? Maybe by minimizing a suitable upper bound? (Please note that I only need to reduce the asymptotic variance of estimates of $\mu g$ for nonnegative $g$.)

Comment: Functions can be written as differences of nonnegative functions, so the non-negativity restriction doesn't specify the problem further. If you have a specific $g$ which you would like to calculate the expectation of, there is the option of importance sampling with respect to something like $\mu ( x ) g ( x )$, but then of course one has to weigh up whether it is any easier to draw samples from this new target. Your question is still too general - trying to reduce the variance of MCMC-based estimators is a large area of research; being more specific about your task will make it easier to help.

Comment: @πr8 Don't you think that we can minimize some worst-case bound? Or find a suitable choice for $(w_i)_{i\in I}$ numerically?

Comment: A possible relaxation is to try to minimise the lag-one autocorrelation of the Markov chain; even this is hard to do analytically. Depending on your proposal kernel, it is usually possible to design an adaptive scheme which can approximately do this on the fly (e.g. by tuning step-sizes). There are also methods where you aim for your chain to have a given `optimal' acceptance rate, this is also done adaptively.

I stress that this is a hard question - if there was a simple way to make the asymptotic variance of a generic Markov chain smaller, everyone would be doing it.

Comment: @πr8 Thank you for your comment. Regarding your last sentence: Maybe you've misunderstood my concern; I'm not asking for choosing a proposal kernel minimizing the asymptotic variance, but for choosing my parameter $(w_i)_{i\in I}$.

Comment: @πr8 The asymptotic variance depends on the proposal kernel and the estimator. If we use, for example, the importance sampling estimator from the paper I've referenced in [my other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/441125/222528), then there is a nice expression for the asymptotic variance. Shouldn't we be able to choose $(w_i)_{i\in I}$ minimize this expression?

Comment: @πr8 Oh, and please note that if $\operatorname{Cov}_\mu[g(X_0),g(X_1)]$ is what you mean by "lage-one autocorrelation", where $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is the Markov chain generated by the Metropolis-Hastings with target distribution $\mu$, then this is precisely what I'm doing! If $\kappa$ denotes the jump kernel associated to $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$, then minimizing $\text{Cov}_\mu[g(X_0),g(X_1)]$ is equivalent to minimizing $\displaystyle\sup_{\substack{g\in L^2(\mu)\\\left\|g\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}=1}}\langle\kappa g,g\rangle_{L^2(\mu)}$ which in turn is equivalent to maximize $(1)$.

Comment: Re: the final comment, I mean specifically taking $g(x) = x$, i.e. the autocorrelation of the chain's location (or in higher dimensions, of one of its coordinates, i.e. $g(x) = x_i$,). Fixing a $g$ (or a very-finite family of $g$) simplifies things a great deal; the point is to get away from the supremum formulation, which is usually quite intractable.

Comment: @πr8 Unfortunately, taking $g(x)=x$ is impossible, since in my application $E$ is infinite-dimensional. However, I'm willing to assume that $E=M^k$, where $M$ is a three-dimensional manifold, and $E'=[0,1)^d$ (both in the mathoverflow question https://mathoverflow.net/q/348358/91890).

Comment: @πr8 Do you think a (kind of self-normalized) estimator of the form as discussed here https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/441125/222528 could relax the problem? (Please take a look at this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/434388/222528, where my setting is better explained. The proposal might depend on the weight, but once I've fixed it, the desired minimization is only with respect to the choice of the weights $(w_i)_{i\in I}$. Since the asymptotic variance depends on the estimator as well, the problem might be relaxed by coming up with a clever estimator.)

Comment: @πr8 Regarding my earlier comment on the importance sampling estimator: I only need to minimize the asymptotic variance of $\mu\frac gp=\lambda g$ for a finite number of bounded $g$. For a fixed $g$ and in my concrete instance of the problem, the asymptotic variance of the importance sampling estimator is $$\sigma^2(w):=\int\mu({\rm d}x)\int_{\{\:p\:>\:0\:\}}\lambda({\rm d}y)\frac{{g(y)}^2}{\sum_{i\in I}q'\left(\varphi_i^{-1}(x),\varphi_i^{-1}(y)\right)w_i(x)q_i(y)}.$$ Do you think we can choose $(w_i)_{i\in I}$ minimizing $\sigma^2(w)$? Asked for that: https://mathoverflow.net/q/348714/91890